# Casting enum value to int when binding to dropdown using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, enums, casting

I have some code that binds an enumeration to a dropdown list, however, I'd like build the dropdown to take the integer value from the enum for the value and the description attribute for the text.

I tried defining the kvPairList as a int/string and casting enumValue and an (int) 
I also tried converting.toInt32

Ideas?

```
<select name="DropDownList1" id="DropDownList1"> 
  <option value="1">Option 1</option> 
  <option value="2">Option 2</option> 
  <option value="3">Option 3/option>  
</select
```

> 

Enum:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    namespace constants
    {
        public enum Options : int
        {

            [Description("Option 1")]
            Option1 = 1,
            [Description("Option 2")]
            Option2 = 3,
            [Description("Option 3")]
            Option3 = 3
        }
    }
```

Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;

public class EnumDescription
{
    public static string GetDescription(System.Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo FieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])FieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        if ((attributes.Length > 0))
            return attributes[0].Description;
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }

    public static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetValuesAndDescription(System.Type enumType)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> kvPairList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        foreach (System.Enum enumValue in System.Enum.GetValues(enumType))
        {
            kvPairList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(enumValue.ToString(), GetDescription(enumValue)));
        }

        return kvPairList;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually cast it to an int before getting the string representation.  Otherwise you are getting the representation of the enumeration, rather than the integer.

```
kvPairList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(((int)enumValue).ToString(), GetDescription(enumValue)));
```

---

Since the value is of type `System.Enum` and not the underlying enum, a cast won't work.  You could otherwise use the appropriate `Convert` method.

```
kvPairList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(Convert.ToInt32(enumValue).ToString(), GetDescription(enumValue)));
```

Comment: I get the same "Cannot convert type 'System.Enum' to 'int'
" as when I tried (int)enumValue.ToString()

Comment: thats because ToString() is being evaluated BEFORE (int). do this: (int)(enumVale.ToString()) it you want the string rep of the int

Comment: @Neil: In that case, you'd have to use one of the conversion methods since enumerations are convertible to the basic value types.

Comment: @Muad, there is no conceivable way `(int)(enumValue.ToString())` will compile.

Comment: @Muad, that is correct, so long as it's a concrete enum, and not an `Enum` as the OP has it (as Jeff notes in the second part of his answer).

Comment: @Jeff M -- Thanks, I Knew it was one of those!  The Convert.ToInt32 method worked great.